# cannot find inspectCode.exe in Comand line tools for resharper

Tags: resharper, sonarqube, command-line-tool

I'm trying to configure SonarQube with resharper rules, i've installed resharper plugin on my SonarQube and download Command line tools form [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html). In every tutorial i've read people are just puting path to inspectCode.exe in resharper options in sonarQube, but there is not such file in that zip which i downloaded. I was goggling and i guess it is because of new resharper 9 and inspectCode.exe was in version 8. So how should i configure my sonarQube now without instactCode.exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong archive is published over there.
Please, wait a day or two - it will be updated.
It will contain inspectCode.exe file.

Update: Please, download it by this link http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/ReSharperCommandLineTools01Update1.zip